# Integrable on subintervals but not integrable on the whole interval

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a complex valued function on the compact interval $[a,b]$. If $f$ is integrable on $[a,s]$ for each $s$ in $(a,b)$, and $\lim_{s \to b^-} \int_a^sf$ exists, is $f$ necessarily integrable on the whole interval $[a,b]$? The answer is written to be no, but I cannot find an appropriate counterexample. Could aynone help me?

Comment: How is integrability defined? Riemann? Lebesgue? For Riemann it is obvious since Riemann integrable functions are bounded. For Lebesgue, cook up a function which is conditionally integrable on $[1,\infty)$ and then change variables to $u=1/x$.

Comment: I meant both. Oh I now get some counterexamples, partly thanks to your comment.